# CKEditor fails to parse style setting

Tags: css, ckeditor

When I save a document in CKEditor (CKEditor 3.5.2), the saved HTML is right. But when I open that HTML again for editing (putting the HTML in a textarea and then load CKEditor), CKEditor parses the style setting wrong.

If I have a code that looks like this:

```
<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 11px; background: green;">Hello</div>
```

And then open it with CKEditor, it looks like this:

```
<div style="font-family: arial font-size: 11px background: green">Hello</div>
```

The ; has disappeared. It does not matter which style settings I use, the semicolon disappears in all cases.

It does not matter what element the style setting is in. The same problem appears in img, div, a, span... and so on.

What shall I do? I am about 100% sure it is ckeditor that is the problem. I open the HTML right from the database. But what else than ckeditor could it be?

I do not use any CMS site, just pure php.

Comment: what version of CKEditor are you using? This issue only happen if you set the font-family, font-size and background?

Comment: What are you using to load the content into CKEditor? You are 100% positive that it's CKEditor doing the mutilating?

Comment: Are you running CKEditor within Drupal or another CMS based site which may be stripping/filtering out the semicolon (;)?

Comment: I am using CKEditor 3.5.2. It does not matter which style settings I use, the semicolon disappears in all cases.

Comment: I just put the code in a textarea and then load CKEditor. I do not use any CMS site, just pure php.

Comment: I've tested the _samples/php/standalone.php demo using   $initialValue = '<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 11px; background: green;">Hello</div>';
 and it's working fine.

Comment: If you disable CKEditor, does the code appear correctly? Also try placing semicolons inside the text, to see if it disappears.

Answer (score -1):

might be some configuration issues.

reinstall properly because i am also using ckeditor it's works fine in all browser and support all kind of html or css tags